# How to download emails into local system using java?

Tags: java, gmail, gmail-imap

I need to download gmail-> emails into my local system. Idea is to convert each 'email's' content into an XML and upload it onto some other system. I am wondering if there is an API which allows me to download 'my' e-mails from gmail account onto a local hard drive (e.g c:\gmail-mails)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code snipped I got from this [site](http://harikrishnan83.wordpress.com/2009/01/24/access-gmail-with-imap-using-java-mail-api/).

```
try {
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
    Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
    store.connect("imap.gmail.com", "<username>", "password");
    System.out.println(store);

    Folder inbox = store.getFolder("Inbox");
    inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
    Message messages[] = inbox.getMessages();
    for(Message message:messages) {
        //TODO store the message cntent in anXML file
    }
} catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();//...
} catch (MessagingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();//...
}
```

And maybe better, also have a look at the [extention of JavaMail](http://code.google.com/p/java-gmail-imap/) Google made.